# Installing GeForce drivers to Kali

Tags: kali-linux, gcc, proprietary-drivers

I'm currently trying to install GeForce drivers for Kali Linux, but it isn't going so smooth.  I have a GTX 285 and when I try the apt-get method for drivers I'm told that my card is no longer supported this way and I need to download the 340.96 drivers from nVidia.  Trouble is, when I try to install it I'm met with "the compiler used to compile the kernel was gcc 5.4; the current compiler is gcc 6.1."

I've attempted my best Google-fu skills but as of yet I've made no progress. None of the fixes I've found have had any effect and since I already uninstalled nouveau I'm getting tired of a 1280x720 display on a 1080p monitor :3 if anyone has any suggestions I'm all ears! Thanks :D

Here's a link to the [nvidia-installer.log file on my Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kvtk80mlo1yopa/nvidia-installer.log?dl=0) -

Answer (score 1):

After spending few days on how-tos and debugging the black screen issue on boot after insalling the nvidia drivers, I was finally able to find a solution to all my problems. The main reason I'm writing this post is to let you know that the tutorial found on Kali's official website is broken as of date 11 April 2018. According to he mentioned in their website you might be able to successfully install the packages - ocl-icd-libopencl1, nvidia-driver, nvidia-cuda-toolkit but you might encounter issues during the reboot. You might get a black screen and won't be able to login via the GUI.
So lets get started-

First of all let me tell you the specifications of my system-

CPU - Intel® Core™ i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz × 8

GPU #1- Intel® UHD Graphics 620

GPU #2- Nvidia GeForce MX150

```
root@europa:~# uname -a
Linux europa 4.14.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.14.17-1kali1 (2018-02-16) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Release-

```
root@europa:~# cat /etc/*release*
DISTRIB_ID=Kali
DISTRIB_RELEASE=kali-rolling
DISTRIB_CODENAME=kali-rolling
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
ID=kali
VERSION="2018.1"
VERSION_ID="2018.1"
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.kali.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://forums.kali.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.kali.org/"
```

Before we begin, a couple of notes:

USE AT YOUR OWN RISK

This tutorial is for official NVIDIA Driver

Tutorial found on official Kali website is BROKEN! It never works for optimus/hybrid Graphics enabled laptop

Step 1: Verify you have hybrid graphics

```
root@europa:~# lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)
```

Step 2: Disable nouveau

```
echo -e "blacklist nouveau\noptions nouveau modeset=0\nalias nouveau off" > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
update-initramfs -u && reboot
```

Step 3: System will reboot and nouveau should be disabled. Verify if nouveau is disabled:

```
lsmod |grep -i nouveau
```

If shows nothing,means nouveau successfully disabled.

Step 4: Install nvidia driver from kali repo:

```
apt-get install  nvidia-driver nvidia-xconfig
```

You can also download latest .run file from Nvidia's website. Execute and procceed with installation. Whether its from Kali's repo or Nvidia's website, procedure is same. Code to install the .run file:

```
sudo sh ./Nvidia-driver-filename.run
```

Step 5: Now we have to find bus id of our nvidia card:

```
nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info | grep 'BusID : ' | cut -d ' ' -f6
```

it should show something like this:

```
PCI:1:0:0
```

This is our Bus ID.

Step 6: Now we generate /etc/X11/xorg.conf file with this bus ID according to Nvidia's guide:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "**PCI:1:0:0**"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier "intel"
   Driver "modesetting"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
   Identifier "intel"
   Device "intel"
EndSection
```

Replace the string inside ** ** with your Bus ID and save it to /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Step 7: Now we have to create some scripts according to our display manager.Since im using default Kali linux which is GDM,i created two files: /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart/optimus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/optimus.desktop with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Optimus
Exec=sh -c "xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0; xrandr --auto"
NoDisplay=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=DisplayServer
```

Step 8: Now reboot and you should be using Nvidia Driver. Verify if everything is ok: install mesa-utils if not previously installed.

```
 apt-get install mesa-utils

 root@europa:~# glxinfo | grep -i "direct rendering" direct rendering: Yes
```

Step 9: Now you can install the cuda toolkits and drivers

```
 apt install -y ocl-icd-libopencl1 nvidia-driver nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Step 10: Now that our system should be ready to go, we need to verify the drivers have been loaded correctly. We can quickly verify this by running the nvidia-smi tool.

```
root@europa:~# nvidia-smi
Wed Apr 11 11:08:55 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------    +
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.42                 Driver Version: 390.42                        |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------     +
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================        |
|   0  GeForce MX150       Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   60C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    368MiB /  2002MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage          |
|=============================================================================    |
|    0       763      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            20MiB |
|    0       793      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          19MiB |
|    0      1108      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            82MiB |
|    0      1191      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         242MiB |
|    0      2132      G   gnome-control-center                           1MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

FIXING SCREEN TEARING ISSUE: After you successfully boot up with Nvidia Driver, you most probably would be experiencing screen tearing issue eg: glitches while playing videos in VLC, Youtube videos on Chrome/Firefox etc. Luckily, we can fix this by enabling PRIME Sync.

1.Verify if PRIME is disabled

```
 xrandr --verbose|grep PRIME
```

it should output something like this:

```
 PRIME Synchronization: 0
 PRIME Synchronization: 1
```

First one is our connected display.So PRIME sync is disabled.

2.Edit /etc/default/grub and append nvidia-drm.modeset=1 in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT after quiet.Like the following:

```
...
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nvidia-drm.modeset=1"
...
```

3.Save the changes and update grub using the command:

```
 update-grub
```

4.Reboot your system.

5.Verify if PRIME is enabled:

```
 xrandr --verbose|grep PRIME
```

Now it should output:

```
 PRIME Synchronization: 1
 PRIME Synchronization: 1
```

If it still shows 0 for you,then there is probably something wrong with your system config/kernel. Since this is still an experimental feature from Nvidia,you are out of luck.

IF YOU STUCK IN BOOT SCREEN

Revert what we have done so far:

Press CTRL+ALT+F2 or CTRL+ALT+F3, login with your password.

```
 apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
 rm -rf /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Remove those display manager files we created earlier (for GDM):

```
 rm -rf /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart/optimus.desktop
 rm -rf /etc/xdg/autostart/optimus.desktop
```

Now reboot. You should be able get back to your old system.

If any issues exist please post it in [Kali's form](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?35748-TUTORIAL-Installing-official-NVIDIA-driver-in-Optimus-laptop).

My sincere thanks to [Tiger11](https://forums.kali.org/member.php?53670-TiGER511) who did all the hard-work.

Comment: We prefer that you not post [identical answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/315792/80216#437586) to different questions.  I have flagged this question as a duplicate of [Installing proprietary NVIDIA drivers in Kali 2016.2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/315792/80216).