# New Kali Linux Installation crashes with green-violet stripes

Tags: kali-linux, system-installation

I tried to install Kali Linux as a second OS on my PC. So I went to kali.org and downloaded the latest version (2019.3) and wrote it with win32 disk imager on a usb and booted from that stick. Installation was successful but when booting it crashes and leaves green-violet stripes (see image).

I’m using a nvidia gtx 2070.

msinfo summary returns:

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Home
Version 10.0.17763 Build 17763
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name COMPUTER
System Manufacturer Acer
System Model    Predator G3-605
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 3401 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   American Megatrends Inc. P11-C1, 12/09/2014
SMBIOS Version  2.7
Embedded Controller Version 255.255
BIOS Mode   UEFI
BaseBoard Manufacturer  Acer
BaseBoard Product   Predator G3-605
BaseBoard Version   
Platform Role   Desktop
Secure Boot State   Off
PCR7 Configuration  Binding Not Possible
Windows Directory   C:\Windows
System Directory    C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume7
Locale  Germany
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "10.0.17763.737"
Username    COMPUTER\Simon
Time Zone   W. Europe Summer Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 8.00 GB
Total Physical Memory   7.92 GB
Available Physical Memory   5.29 GB
Total Virtual Memory    18.9 GB
Available Virtual Memory    14.6 GB
Page File Space 11.0 GB
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
Kernel DMA Protection   Off
Virtualisation-based security   Not enabled
Device Encryption Support   Reasons for failed automatic device encryption: TPM is not usable, PCR7 binding is not supported, Hardware Security Test Interface failed and the device is not InstantGo, Un-allowed DMA-capable bus/device(s) detected, TPM is not usable
Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions    Yes
Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions   Yes
Hyper-V - Virtualisation Enabled in Firmware    Yes
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection Yes
```

[image: Crashed kali]

**EDIT:** The solution was to disable the nouveau drivers with a boot param following Freddys instructions, get a shell and then update and install the nvidia software.

Comment: It looks like it's an issue with the nvidia driver. Can you disable the card in the BIOS and try if it works with the onboard Intel HD 4600 (Intel [told me](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75122/intel-core-i7-4770-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html))? And what model is your nvidia card? Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/544142/edit) your question and add the information.

Comment: Thx. my bios only offers to disable. Sata-, USB-, Audio- and LAN Controller in advanced > integrated peripherals and only intel settings in advanced chipset config. Google says that there should be a video controller or something with PCIe in some cases but neither exist in my bios. What am I missing?

Comment: I have no idea. Try booting with kernel parameter `nouveau.modeset=0`:
Select the grub boot entry, press `e` and add the parameter to the line containing "linux" and press F10 to boot (see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters#Temporarily_Add_a_Kernel_Boot_Parameter_for_Testing)).
If that works you can blacklist the nouveau driver and install the nvidia driver, like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315792/installing-proprietary-nvidia-drivers-kali-2016-2) (the answers are probably outdated, but the procedure should be similar).

Comment: If you need to use msinfo to determine what's on your system, I would respectfully suggest to you that Kali is not a distribution you want to try to run. Or using ms disk imager. Once you can run linux and linux tools, Kali is more interesting, for certain advanced use cases, and for advanced users who can benefit from those features.

Comment: @Freddy your suggestion worked like a charm. I was able to get a terminal to install the nvidia software. thx a lot.

Comment: Please consider adding an actual answer to your own question, rather than modifying the question itself. That way you may accept your own answer and the question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to disable the nouveau drivers with a boot param following Freddys instructions, get a shell and then update and install the nvidia software.